# solana spl-token transfer fee "Error: Program(IncorrectProgramId)"

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, solana, fee

I want to create my own Solana token that takes %2 fee to all transactions and total supply should be 100k token. That's why i used `spl-token` cli for this `spl-token create-token --transfer-fee 50 1000`, however after executing this command i get an error like

> Error: Program(IncorrectProgramId)

How can i fix this error or how can i create my own token with transaction fee.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new token with transfer fees, you must specify the program id as the token-2022 program id of `TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb`, so instead, do:

```
spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb create-token --transfer-fee 50 1000
```